# soft copy of Ottmar loos's book on "symmetric spaces"

Tags: soft-question

Is anyone in posssesion of the Ottmar Loos's old books on "Symmetric Spaces" . I have consulted Ottmar Loos himself as well as other experts like Prof.Parameshwaran Shankaran about the book. In their opinion there is none available right now online. The book is a good complement to Helgason's which is a extremely demanding book .

Comment: amazon.com are listing used copies for reasonable prices.

Comment: Another good place to find math books is http://www.bookfinder.com// -- I actually found my copies of Loos' books that way

Comment: I once contacted Prof.Loos. He implied that there might be a forthcoming AMS version of the two old volumes.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I'll mention that many years ago I owned copies of his two volumes but eventually (maybe when I retired and moved to a shared office) those books and many others went to someone else.    But even now the UMass Amherst science library does have copies on the shelf (and in the remote Five College storage facility: a Cold War SAC bunker intended to preserve bank records but now owned by Amherst College, under one of the nearby small mountains).   But you might do best to try Amazon if US interlibrary loan services aren't available to you.

P.S.  Out of curiosity, I checked what else seemed to be on offer on the internet.
[Here](http://www.alibris.com/Symmetric-spaces-Ottmar-Loos/book/6501955?qsort=p&matches=1) is another possibility, though I have no idea what the format is.   The original two 1969 volumes totalled under 400 pages of photocopied typescript, in the softcover W.A. Benjamin lecture note series.